# Spring Social: "Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in"

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to use Facebook sign in as described in 
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook

When I'm trying to create JdbcUsersConnectionRepository, I need spring security in class path.
And when I add spring security I receive

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in"
```

when trying to receive Connection

```
Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
```

or checking

```
if (!facebook.isAuthorized())
```

All this happens only when spring security is in the class path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Social Connection should be correspond to any auth user. It seems user should login through username/password or Service Provider. Try look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in"
```

It happens because [AuthenticationNameUserIdSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/25d7245f5c59dee5252a7196551db3543b514fdf/spring-social-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/security/AuthenticationNameUserIdSource.java) used by default

> Internally, Spring Social’s configuration support will use the UsersConnectionRepository to create a request-scoped ConnectionRepository bean. In doing so, it must identify the current user. Therefore, we must also override the getUserIdSource() to return an instance of a UserIdSource.
>
> In this case, we’re returning an instance of AuthenticationNameUserIdSource. This implementation of the UserIdSource interface assumes that the application is secured with Spring Security. It uses the SecurityContextHolder to lookup a SecurityContext, and from that return the name property of the Authentication object.
>
> If your application isn’t secured with Spring Security, you’ll need to implement the UserIdSource interface as approprate for your application’s security mechanism. The UserIdSource interface looks like this:

```
package org.springframework.social;
public interface UserIdSource {
    String getUserId();
}
```

> The getUserId() method simply returns a String that uniquely identifies the current user.

More info [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/dcf404f1fe2b851d901ab972afbfcf2f6306d490/docs/manual/src/asciidoc/index.adoc#configuring-connectcontroller)

Comment: Can you point me to an example of UserIdSource  implementation for Facebook?

In order to return a user id I need to know whether a use is connected. And I can't do it because I can't call 
connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class)

Comment: @PavelBernshtam Hello! Why your user not login in and you try to get social connection for him (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is null)? Social Connection should be correspond to any user. It seems user should login through username/password or Service Provider. Do you try http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring boot, then the property security basic should not be set to false. Hide this line in your `application.properties`. This disables the security and boot throws the error if spring-security is disabled.

```
#security.basic.enabled=false
```